# Limit Repeating Addition Quiz- While loop - Java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to code in `Java` and started with a basic repeating addition quiz.

Repeating addition until enter the correct answer works fine, however, when I try to limit it to 3 trials, it does not stop at 3, but goes for 4 trials as shown below,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeatAdditionQuiz {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is " + number1  + " + " + number2 + " : " );
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 3) {

        if (number1 + number2 != answer) {
            System.out.print("Try again, What is " + number1  + " + " + number2 + " : " );
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("You're correct ");

        count ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Your trails ended ");

}

}
```

This is my output,

```
What is 1 + 2 : 8
Try again, What is 1 + 2 : 6
Try again, What is 1 + 2 : 9
Try again, What is 1 + 2 : 9
Your trails ended
```

As you can see I have four trails with the first one. When I tried to remove first user input before `while` loop (which prints `What is 1 + 2 :`), I don't see anything in console. How can I just limit it to 3?

In `python` I can do something like this,

```
from random import randint

number1 = randint(0,9)
number2 = randint(0,9)

answer = number1 + number2
count = 0
while count < 3:
    print(number1, "+", number2)
    user_answer = int(input("What is number1  + number2: "))
    if answer == user_answer:
        print("yes, you're right")
        break
    else:
        print("You're wrong, please enter again")
    count +=1
print("Sorry, all trials are done! ")
```

And I get the output like this, exactly three trails (every time I enter wrong answer),

```
8 + 5
What is number1  + number2: 16
You're wrong, please enter again
8 + 5
What is number1  + number2: 18
You're wrong, please enter again
8 + 5
What is number1  + number2: 18
You're wrong, please enter again
Sorry, all trials are done!
```

What mistake am I making in `java`? Is there any better way to do in `while` loop? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You have specified four inputs: one before the `while` loop and three in the `while` loop. If you want three in total ...

Comment: @dave yes, I need three in total, but as mentioned in the question, when i take off the input statement before while loop, it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use do-while loop in  situation like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeatAdditionQuiz {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " : ");
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    int count = 1;
    do {

        if (number1 + number2 != answer) {
            System.out.print("Try again, What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " : ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
        } else{
            System.out.println("You're correct ");
            break;
        }
        count++;
    } while (count < 3);
    System.out.println("Your trails ended ");

}

}
```

In this I initialize count as 1 because we already provide answer an input at the time of instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your main method to be something like Below. Basically it is your code with change suggested by Dave and a break statement in else block.

Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is " + number1  + " + " + number2 + " : " );
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 2) {

        if (number1 + number2 != answer) {
            System.out.print("Try again, What is " + number1  + " + " + number2 + " : " );
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You're correct ");
            break;
        }


        count ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Your trails ended ");

}
```

Comment: yes, as Dave suggested this is one way. However, is there any way that i can say `count < 3` and start count from `0` as I showed in `python`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is initially you are asking to guess the answer and then initializing the count as 0.

```
int answer = input.nextInt();
int count = 0;
```

You have already asked user for the 1st trail,so initialize count as 1.

```
int count = 1;
```

Another way to solve these kind of problems is to use do-while as mentioned by @Ayush Goyal.

Answer (score 0):

To be close to your Python example you can try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 3) {

         System.out.print("What is " + number1  + " + " + number2 + " : " );
         answer = input.nextInt();

        if (number1 + number2 != answer) {
        System.out.println("You're wrong, please enter again");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You're correct ");
            break;
        }


        count ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Your trails ended ");

}
```